# Obtaining realtime friend request notifications from the graph or stream api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I need to obtain realtime friend request notifications if possible, I know I can query the fql Friend_Request table uor use the graph api, but was wondering whether friend requests can be obtained in realtime via the stream api.
Any help apreciated. I am using asp.net but am familar with php if samples are available in that language only.

Answer (score 0):

See the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/ to subscribe to events.

> Here are the list of User connections to which you can subscribe:
>   feed, friends, activities, interests, music, books, movies,
>   television, likes, checkins.
>
> You can't subscribe to these User connections yet: home, tagged,
>   posts, photos, albums, videos, groups, notes, events, inbox, outbox,
>   updates, accounts.

As you can see, "requests" is not an object currently.  So I'd say you're going to have to use the FQL polling method until Facebook adds that relationship.